# Directory for require_once() exist but error says it doesn't

Tags: php, loops, require

so I am writing a loop where I manually input files to be checked, however, when I add it into the require() function, it says it doesn't exist. I tried putting it in the same directory as the php file that checks it and in other directories.

My directorys: The file I use to check other files is under core so I set the require path based on that. I wanted to check files in assets by settings its path back one (./example.php) but it failed.

www -> assets -> core

My Paths(These show my latest attempts at finding them in the relative path):

```
$PATH_CONFIG = "config.php";
$PATH_DBASE = "dbconnect.php";
$PATH_JQUERYMIN ="./assets/scripts/jquery.1.9.1.min.js";
$PATH_SWITCHMIN ="./assets/scripts/switchMin.js";
```

My loop (so I don't have to do so many requires):

```
$checklist = array($PATH_CONFIG, $PATH_DBASE);
$listsize = sizeof($checklist, 1);

for ($x = 0; $x < $listsize; $x++) {
    if(!file_exists($checklist[$x])){
        echo "Unable to load website: $checklist[$x] is missing!";
        exit;
    } require($checklist[$x]);
}
```

Error thrown: Unable to load website: config.php is missing! (this is the catch I made to see which file is not loading.

From above:

```
echo "Unable to load website: $checklist[$x] is missing!";
```

Comment: What does your `get_include_path();` return?

Comment: This is not a solution, but you can debug this issue with
`var_dump(scandir('./'));`

Comment: Oh, and btw... if you are wanting to go 'back' one directory, you use `../` NOT `./`.

Comment: @IncredibleHat hmm, it returns .;C:\php\pear no matter which directory its in. When I had the check file in the assets folder, I remember I had to make it go back a directory(root) before it worked. so ./assets/core/config.php worked previously.

Comment: Using `./` just tells it 'start in the same directory'. Which works if you happen to already be in the same directory. This is where you probably should define a base path that everything grows from, and use that as the defining piece of all paths. Using something like `__DIR__` is dynamic to the file (so long as you dont keep shifting that file around in sub dirs).

Comment: @IncredibleHat so I just added a require('config.php') and it found it, so it must be something within the array / for loop. But I can't figure it out. Not sure why it worked before but doesn't now.

Comment: Depends, you mentioned at one point you had the test script inside a sub directory. Which means `require('config.php');` would not find that inside the sub directory (its one directory UP, thus `require('../config.php');`).

Comment: when requiring files that are in a dir from different dirs with the same function, use absolute url instead of rel one, it will gives you a stable behaviour.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Currently it is in the same folder as the check script, so I have it set to just config.php without any directory changes. But it still can't find it.